# Set up staging environments in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice, azure-webapps

I followed this article to learn about staging environments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots. What are the code changes required in order to set up staging environments in Azure App Service?

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think code changes are required? A staging slot is in its essence it is just a deployment target.

That said, the one thing I can think of is making sure your application does not contain hardcoded configuration that is different between test and prod environments.

If the ARM template is well parameterized it won't need any changes too. The build pipeline should be able to deploy to multiple environments (dev/test, prod etc) by supplying different parameters to the template.

Comment: Thank you! I need to set up a staging slot and during deployment, it should be deployed to staging slot and then to production slot. Curious to know the steps required for the same.

Comment: *Curious to know the steps required for the same.* What do you mean?

Comment: arm template changes to deploy to a staging slot first.

Comment: @user989988 see updated answer. Are you using azure devops pipelines?

Comment: @user989988 feel free to [accept any answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was of any help to you. If it isn't, feel free to ask for details.